# ansible file to deploy a particular version of elastic search

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ansible

I am trying to convert my docker-compose.yml which deploy elastic search to  an ansible.yml file to deploy a elastic search server.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# Run both the app and Elasticsearch inside Docker containers.
version: '3'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

I converted the above docker-comps file as below but it did not throw any error but never deploy an elastic search.
**ansible.yml**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "Elasticsearch"
      docker_container:
        name: "es01"
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
        volumes:
          - "sdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
        env:
          node.name: es01
          cluster.initial_master_nodes: es01
          cluster.name: docker-cluster
          bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"
```

I checked the  official elastic search ansible page (https://github.com/elastic/ansible-elasticsearch/blob/master/README.md) and I am having a difficulty to understand it.

Could someone please  advice why my **ansible.yml** is not able to deploy elastic search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your error even though I found some things in your `playbook` that could create problems:

1. You are using `localhost` as your `host` value, but you are not setting your connection method to `local`. As the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/local.html) says:

> This connection plugin allows ansible to execute tasks on the Ansible ‘controller’ instead of on a remote host.

2. You are not escaping the dots `.` of the `env` dictionary keys.

Nonetheless, the `playbook` either runs or not, which is not your behavior.

Here is my `playbook`:

```
- name: Elasticsearch
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    project_name: es
    es_version: '7.2.0'
  tasks:
    - name: Docker Network
      docker_network:
        state: 'present'
        name: '{{ project_name }}_network'

    - name: ES 01 Docker Volume
      docker_volume:
        state: 'present'
        name: '{{ project_name }}_volume_01'

    - name: "Elasticsearch Docker Container"
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ project_name }}_01"
        state: started
        image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:{{ es_version }}'
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
        ulimits:
          - 'memlock:-1:-1'
        volumes:
          - "{{ project_name }}_volume_01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
        env:
          node.name: es01
          cluster.initial_master_nodes: es01
          cluster.name: docker-cluster
          bootstrap.memory_lock: 'true'
          'ES_JAVA_OPTS': '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
```

And here is my `hosts.yml` file:

```
all:
  children:
    local:
      hosts:
        localhost:
```

I have also added a variable called `es_version` which you can override to install the Elastisearch version you like.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not try this out yet. I will accept this answer once, I tried it.

Comment: I ran your play book but elastci search does not start for me. it shows following output

Comment: `ansible-playbook ansible.yml
 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note
that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: local


PLAY [Elasticsearch] ***********************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************`

Comment: I believe your problem is regarding the `hosts` group you are using. I have updated my answer to show the inventory I am using. Adapt you `playbook` accordingly.

Comment: I put the host.yml in /etc/ansible/hosts and ran ansible-playbook ansible.yml. Then it worked. Thanks